# Nginx Dynamic Location Block Alias

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use alias folder for inside `Nginx` blocks but after lots of struggle i can not manage to success it. Here is my error code.

```
"GET https://abctasarim.com/en/products/seismic-isolator-mold-release-agent/js/modules/sliderdimensions.js/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"
```

I have tried the rule

```
location  ~ ^/products/(.?)/js/modules/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
    #add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

But I am getting 404. I have tried many possible combinations.

Could you please help me,

Thanks

ps: working hard-coded rule:

```
location /en/products/seismic-isolator-mold-release-agent/js/modules/  {
     autoindex on;
     alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/js/modules/;
     expires 365d;
     access_log off;
     #add_header Cache-Control "public";
     #proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

Comment: What if the exact pathname of the file that should be returned for the given URL?

Comment: @RichardSmith still same, I am using Django/Gunicorn and nginx settings, I will add the rule which works, but I do not want to use it for all addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your working code, the URL `/en/products/.../js/modules/foo.js` is located at `/home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/js/modules/foo.js`

Looking at your failed code, you want to ignore the `en` prefix and the long description between `product` and `js/modules`.

Your `location` regular expression is wrong as it does not allow for the `en` prefix and I'm not sure what `.?` is for. Perhaps you meant `.*?` which is a non-greedy match for any string.

Using `alias` within a regular expression location requires you to capture the entire tail of the URL and append it to the `alias` value. See [the `alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ /products/.*?/(js/modules/.*)$ {
    alias /home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/$1;
    ...
}
```